# Multiple Account Types MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am building an app utilizing the MERN stack (MongoDB, Express.js, React/Redux, Node.js) where there will be three user account types: `Client, Company, Admin`.

Client account can search and partner with Company accounts where they can submit orders.
Company account will be a paid subscription (via Stripe) where they can complete orders submitted by client accounts.
Admin will be an interface to view all users, orders, etc..

I am trying to determine the best approach for create multiple user account types in Mongo. I assume there will need to be two different registration forms. I'd like a single login form that will determine if an account is client or company and display relevant information based on their role.

Looking for input on the best/most scalable approach for this.

Comment: Role-Based Access Control, on login check for user role which is tied to your login collection.